# bash + PERL hybrid script

Tags: script, bash-scripting, perl

I am new to this community, I tried to find relevant answers but could not find any.

My question is, I want to use perl script in a directory of files ending with .fasta, if I do in bash as

```
for i in *.fasta
do
perl script.pl
done
```

Question is: How can I use bash variable $i value in PERL script.
The perl script opens each file, perform certain functions on each file and closes it. like

```
my $file1 = 'All-Sequences.fasta'; # I want to replace 'All-Sequences.fasta' with $i
open (FILE, $file);
my @file = <FILE>;
close FILE;
print @file;
```

These are exemplary functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can access parameters given to the Perl script with the @ARGV array, so you could do this:

```
my $fileName = $ARGV[0];
your code...
```

And run it with:

```
for i in *.fasta
do
  perl script.pl "$i"
done
```

You could also find the .fasta directories with a Perl function of course and then loop over those results.

Comment: I got it, @ARGV has ability to get external values which is a great functionality of PERL. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by mtak is most simple.  It can be easily modified to pass more than one filename but there is a system depended limit of number of command line arguments.

**If** you prefer answer tuned for performance for *huge* number of files **then** you may feed list of files via pipe between bash (parent process) and perl (child process).
It avoids starting perl interpreter many times and hitting limits on number of command line arguments.

bash script:

```
for i in *.fasta ; do
  echo $i
done | perl script.pl
```

perl script

```
while (<STDIN>) {
  # get file name
  chomp;     
  my $file = $_;

  # process file named $file
  open (my $FILE,'<', $file) or die "Can't open: $!";
     my @file = <$FILE>;
  close $FILE;
  print @file;
}
```